# Unifying tag spellings

Tags: discussion, retag-request

It’s not that big of a deal, but I have noticed there are a couple of tags that correspond to versions of a product line that are spelt differently from tags corresponding to other members of that same product line. It would be nice to rename them to keep some consistency:

- Windows tags: [windows31](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows31) → [windows-3.1](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-3.1) to match [windows-95](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-95), [windows-98](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-98), [windows-me](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-me). Perhaps even generalise it to [windows-3.x](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-3.x).
- x86 CPU tags: [386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/386) → [80386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80386) to match [80186](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80186), [80286](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80286) and [80486](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80486)

The old spellings should be kept as synonyms, of course.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to keep [tag:windows31] as a synonym – unless that was actually a name people used for the OS before this site popped up.

Comment: Well, I don’t particularly care about keeping that synonym, but I imagine it might help those who might use the old spelling by habit. It’s not like it might conflict with any ‘Windows 31’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've renamed [386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/386) to [80386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80386) by swapping the synonym then clicking “merge” – this only kept the tag wiki excerpt properly because no questions were tagged [80386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80386). (The tag management tools, while much better than they used to be, are still a little arcane; this paragraph is documentation.)

I also created [windows-3.1](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-3.1) as a synonym of [windows31](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows31), which I renamed to [windows-3.x](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-3.x).

Comment: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2386/ uses the tag, but the question body specifically mentions Windows 3.0; likewise does https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11242/ and https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6705/. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11800/ and https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13763/ specify the version as ‘3.x’ in the body. So I think in practice it’s generalised already.

Comment: Well that solves that problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user3840170 Done.

Comment: It's doing weird things. I'll blame caching and check back tomorrow.